# Remove duplicates in a subarrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, sub-array

I am wondering if anyone can advise on how to remove duplicate items from just the subarray with items that have the same key `color`. From the example below index 0 has the colors `red`, `blue` and `green` and the second one has `red`, `purple`, `red`. I want the duplicates to be removed at the index level so that the output of index 0 should remain `red`, `blue`, `green` and the output of index 2 `red`, `purple`.

```
$array = [
    [
        ['color' => 'RED'],
        ['color' => 'BLUE'],
        ['color' => 'GREEN']
    ],
    [
        ['color' => 'RED'],
        ['color' => 'PURPLE'],
        ['color' => 'RED']
    ]

];

$new_array = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $new_array[] = array_unique($item);
}

echo json_encode($new_array);
```

this code outputs

```
[[{"color":"RED"}],[{"color":"RED"}]]
```

and therefore just removing duplicated of the same key. The output needs to be:

```
[[{"color":"RED"},{"color":"BLUE"},{"color":"GREEN"}],[{"color":"RED"},{"color":"PURPLE"}]]
```

Comment: Why do you use 'color' index? It's similar for all elements

Comment: Its just an example but will be necessary further down the line when making guzzle calls etc

Comment: you can just set array like this: `$array = [
            ['RED','BLUE','GREEN'],
            ['RED','PURPLE','RED']
        ];
` - it seems to work well then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler, more elegant approach to removing duplicates that relies on the fact that php array may not have duplicate keys on the same level.  Using `array_column()` to assign temporary keys while not modifying the subarray's structure, subarrays with recurring keys will be purged.  After removing the duplicates, just call `array_values()` to re-index the subarray.  I will be using `&` so that the input array is modified by reference -- this way no new variables need to be generated in the global scope.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/b6AE6))

```
foreach ($array as &$row) {
    $row = array_values(array_column($row, null, 'color'));
}
var_export($array);
```

---

Code without modifying the input array: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XiAfe))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $result[] = array_values(array_column($row, null, 'color'));
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Great stuff thanks a lot, this also works great